# How to set absolute Url for web worker in Angular

Tags: angular, web-worker, angular10

I have started using web workers at first with success in my application.

After I started to add routing to the application, the web worker stopped working correctly.

I see that the call to the web worker is always relative to the URL I am on.
[image]
[image]
[image]

If I call my web worker when I am at the root of my project it will work. This is without the 'app'
as part of the path.

When I navigate deeper I lose reference to the file URL that I set.

If i try to set the web worker URL reference as absolute that also does not work. I get the error message below.

[image]

But somehow the URL of the web worker when it is working correctly is different. The URL I declare is not the one that is used at runtime. So somehow the compiler is involved in this process.
[image]

Has anyone with experience with web workers and angular got any idea when is going on?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem. The problem here is that I had not implemented the hashing in the Router module.

[image]